Why edges doesn't render in react flow?
I am new at react flow. My goal is connect to nodes with same type. I want to have one template for node and use it everywhere.
Below simple example, but edges doesn't appear.
If i remove type in nodes  everything fine.
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import "reactflow/dist/style.css";
import TextUpdaterNode from "./TextUpdaterNode.js";
import "./text-updater-node.css";

const rfStyle = {
  backgroundColor: "#B8CEFF"
};

const initialNodes = [
  {
    id: "1",
    position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    type: "textUpdater"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    position: { x: 0, y: 100 },
    type: "textUpdater"
  }
];

const initialEdges = [{ id: "e1-2", source: "1", target: "2", animated: true }];

const nodeTypes = { textUpdater: TextUpdaterNode };

function Flow() {
  return (
    <ReactFlow
      nodes={initialNodes}
      edges={initialEdges}
      nodeTypes={nodeTypes}
      fitView
      style={rfStyle}
    />
  );
}

export default Flow;


To solve your issue, you need to ensure that TextUpdaterNode component is correctly implemented and to register the custom node type in the nodeTypes prop of ReactFlow.
TextUpdaterNode:
import React from 'react';
import { Handle, Position } from 'reactflow';

const TextUpdaterNode = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className="text-updater-node">
      <Handle type="target" position={Position.Top} />
      <div>{data.label}</div>
      <Handle type="source" position={Position.Bottom} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextUpdaterNode;


For flow.js:
import React from 'react';
import ReactFlow from 'reactflow';
import 'reactflow/dist/style.css';
import TextUpdaterNode from './TextUpdaterNode';
import './text-updater-node.css';

const rfStyle = {
  backgroundColor: '#B8CEFF',
};

const initialNodes = [
  {
    id: '1',
    position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    type: 'textUpdater',
    data: { label: 'Node 1' },
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    position: { x: 0, y: 100 },
    type: 'textUpdater',
    data: { label: 'Node 2' },
  },
];

const initialEdges = [
  { id: 'e1-2', source: '1', target: '2', animated: true },
];

const nodeTypes = { textUpdater: TextUpdaterNode };

function Flow() {
  return (
    <ReactFlow
      nodes={initialNodes}
      edges={initialEdges}
      nodeTypes={nodeTypes}
      fitView
      style={rfStyle}
    />
  );
}

export default Flow;

You can also add the following CSS:
.text-updater-node {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


The issue with edges not appearing could be due to how the TextUpdaterNode component is defined or registered

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
